# Selenium doesn't load on Firefox 4

Tags: firefox, selenium, automated-tests

After a recent upgrade to Firefox 4, all of my automated selenium tests seem to be hanging on the initial 'Launching Firefox...' command during testing.

Has anyone seen a fix for this, or is my best bet to downgrade?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you updated to Selenium 2.0b3?  Earlier versions don't support FF4.

*** EDIT* **

RC2 is now available:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

Answer (score 1):

Recommend you to use latest version of selenium with firefox 4. for me it is working fine withoutany problem.

I am using : 
`Selenium Server : selenium-server-2.0b2`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. 'Launching Firefox' command, a blank Firefox window opens and the test hangs. Looking at the Firefox Add-ons the three extensions that Selenium installs were all incompatible and disabled. Turns out my test was still accidentally starting up the wrong selenium version. Switching to 2.0b3 fixed the issue.